# JQuery Datatable not working on pivot table

Tags: jquery, datatables

jquery datatable throwing error while trying on pivot table.

```
$('#my-sampletable').DataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true, 
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [],
            "iDisplayLength":25
            });
```

Corresponding fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cqfgaj35/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When asking this question try to post a formatted HTML code.

The reason for this error: Count your `th` columns in `thead`. It has to be the same amount of the columns in `td` in the `tbody` tag.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: https://jsfiddle.net/8wykj1oh/. Be sure that you have the right numbers and try to remove the rowspan in `th`.